# libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException - python on MAC

Tags: python, macos, python-turtle

I am writing a game with python on a MAC PC and I am getting the following error:

`libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException`

The [SnakeGame](https://github.com/GaiAshk/SnakeGame/tree/main) is written so the player can be able to run using [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) or [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).

The game is working just fine when running it with pygame, but when switching to turtle I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15be965f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b930570 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018b421eb4 objc_exception_throw + 60
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b9e212c -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b89a7d4 ___forwarding___ + 1572
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b89a0f0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
        5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f0d9788 GetRGBA + 48
        6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f0d9258 SetCGColorComponents + 144
        7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f0d95e8 TkpGetColor + 344
        8   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f03b508 Tk_GetColor + 220
        9   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f02eb90 Tk_Get3DBorder + 204
        10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f02e9a0 Tk_Alloc3DBorderFromObj + 144
        11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f03c8b4 DoObjConfig + 832
        12  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f03c470 Tk_InitOptions + 348
        13  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f03c36c Tk_InitOptions + 88
        14  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f063e30 CreateFrame + 1432
        15  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f064128 TkListCreateFrame + 156
        16  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010f05d0bc Initialize + 1848
        17  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x000000010eeaa34c Tcl_AppInit + 80
        18  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x000000010eea48a4 Tkapp_New + 592
        19  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x000000010eea428c _tkinter_create + 608
        20  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f0edcc cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 260
        21  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec4844 PyObject_Vectorcall + 80
        22  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa49e4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 33788
        23  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c548 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        24  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec41c0 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 272
        25  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec4f10 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 160
        26  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f3175c slot_tp_init + 188
        27  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f27258 type_call + 424
        28  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec43a8 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 344
        29  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa49e4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 33788
        30  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c548 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        31  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec41c0 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 272
        32  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec4f10 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 160
        33  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f3175c slot_tp_init + 188
        34  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f27258 type_call + 424
        35  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec43a8 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 344
        36  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa49e4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 33788
        37  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c548 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        38  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f97c1c builtin___build_class__ + 1148
        39  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f0ee8c cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 160
        40  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec4844 PyObject_Vectorcall + 80
        41  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa49e4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 33788
        42  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c418 PyEval_EvalCode + 272
        43  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f98f50 builtin_exec + 916
        44  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f0ee8c cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 160
        45  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa6504 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 40732
        46  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c548 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        47  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec5e90 object_vacall + 248
        48  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec5d00 PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs + 92
        49  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fd4a14 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1308
        50  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa1e14 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22572
        51  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c418 PyEval_EvalCode + 272
        52  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f98f50 builtin_exec + 916
        53  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f0ee8c cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 160
        54  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa6504 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 40732
        55  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c548 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        56  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec5e90 object_vacall + 248
        57  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100ec5d00 PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs + 92
        58  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fd4a14 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1308
        59  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fa1e14 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22572
        60  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100f9c418 PyEval_EvalCode + 272
        61  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fef2c8 run_mod + 152
        62  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fed7bc _PyRun_SimpleFileObject + 852
        63  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000100fed244 _PyRun_AnyFileObject + 160
        64  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x000000010100cd0c Py_RunMain + 1848
        65  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x000000010100d0bc pymain_main + 324
        66  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x000000010100d15c Py_BytesMain + 40
        67  dyld                                0x000000018b45d0e0 start + 2360
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

I looked online a lot and saw similar errors for developers using swift.

Comment: Could you share the code as a [mcve] in the question itself?